# Compare two strings in shell, one coming from a command return

Tags: string, shell, variables, if-statement, bluetooth

I'd like to compare two strings to know if my Bluetooth is on or off using [blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/)

I tried this :

```
cd ../../../usr/local/bin
./blueutil status
a=$(./blueutil status)
printf "$a\n"
if [ "$a" = "Status: on" ]
    then echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

But the return is

```
Status: on
Status: on
not ok
```

What is wrong with my test in the if statement?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Oh brother... First we need to know what you get back from .`/blueutil` for each case? does a positive value mean *on* and a negative (or zero) value mean *off*? Are you values  `-1, 0, 1` or different values?

Comment: Ok you're right ./blueutil status gives the first Status: on
So it's not a boolean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `blueutil` is but your script appears to have syntax errors. In some places, whitespaces are critical and missing them leads to incorrect results. In particular, you are missing the space after `[`, before `]` and around `=`. That is, your conditional should be:

```
if [ "$a" = "Status: on" ]
    then echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated it, and it still doesn't working...
For the record, ./blueutil status returns "Status: on" if the Bluetooth is on and returns "Status: off" if it is off.

Comment: Can you please update your question with your new code. Preferrably as an addition below your current code so that the history is maintained. It works for me with a [simple example](http://ideone.com/aHxO23) that doesn't use blueutil.

Comment: Ok it seems I had a typo which implied an error! It is now working, many thanks!